# monitor/alert data types in Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services

how to monitor/alert when new data types are loaded or data size of existing data types doubles to AWS?  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question does not have enough detail for us to be able to answer. For example, what do you mean by "when new data types are loaded"? Into which AWS system are you loading them? Feel free to edit your question to add more detail, such as letting us know what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried so far and what difficulties you are facing. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to more specific , please provide details like what services are you talking about , what data type are you referring ?